# Optimizing VBA codes - row height based on cell values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to adjust the row height based on the cell value. The operation have to run through filtered data with around 700 rows.

The code below works, but it take 2-3 minutes to finish the operation, which is way too long.

Is there any chance I can do this without a loop?
Or is there anything else I should do to shorten the operation time?

```
Sub rowheight()

Dim hgt As Integer
Dim WorkRng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set WorkRng = Range("AJ6:AJ700")
   
For Each C In WorkRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    If C.Value > 0 Then
        hgt = C.Value
        C.EntireRow.rowheight = hgt
    End If
Next C

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: You are handling 1 row. For each cell with data, you adjust the row's heigth. So you set it and set it and set it and.... Why not go through the row to determine once the heigth and then after that set it only once?

Comment: would you mind showing me how to determine the row height at once?

Comment: Does hgt vary from row to row, or is it constant?

Comment: Did you tried `Range("AJ6:AJ700").EntireRow.AutoFit`

Comment: @KarthickGunasekaran Sadly it doesn't work and I have tried the wrap text function as well. Also, autofit is not ideal, since I would like to leave some more space between the rows.

Comment: @Daniel Height varies from row to row.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim i As Long, arr As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        arr = .Range("AJ6:AJ700")

        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

            If arr(i, 1) > 0 Then
                .Rows(i + 5).EntireRow.rowheight = arr(i, 1)
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sadly, this doesn't work, since I am working on filtered data. This operation will unfiltered everything. Also, it seems that this code take even longer to complete the operation...

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that most of the processing is in setting the row heigth, and assuming you want to set it to the largest value, The function would become:

```
Sub rowheight()
    Dim hgt As Integer
    Dim WorkRng As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set WorkRng = Range("AJ6:AJ700")

    hgt = 0
    For Each c In WorkRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If c.Value > hgt Then
            hgt = c.Value
        End If
    Next c
    WorkRng.EntireRow.rowheight = hgt

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I assigned a specific row height value to each row, so I am not trying to set it to the largest value. is there any chance I can store the values in an array, but I am not very sure how to do it...